# Distinct Enumerable DataTable based on column?

Tags: c#, datatable

This is what i'm trying to accomplish.  I want to select only distinct values from all Rows in Column[0].

Then I want to get all the distinct values from column[2] and group them on column[0].

so basically i got a DataTable like so:

```
Fruit|Apples
Fruit|Pears
Vegetables|Peas
Vegetables|Carrots
```

so I want to do a foreach on the distinct values, so I would Enumerate Fruit once and then pick up Apples and Pears, and VegeTables once and pick up Peas and Carrots.

I'm doing this to create Accordion Panes, where I want to group my results under one header, the below code does such, however, it creates two panes of Fruit because it does not realize it already went though fruit.

```
 foreach (DataRow dtrow in dtTable.Rows)
        {
            string idRow = dtrow[0].ToString();
            AccordionPane currentPane = new AccordionPane();
            currentPane.ID = "AccordionPane" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            currentPane.HeaderContainer.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(dtrow[0].ToString()));
            foreach(DataRow dtRow2 in dtTable.Rows)
            {
                if(dtRow2[0].ToString() == idRow)
                {
                    currentPane.ContentContainer.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(dtRow2[1].ToString()));
                }
            }
            NavigateAccordion.Panes.Add(currentPane);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this easily when using linq, see for yourself:

```
var groupedRows = from row in dtTable.Rows.AsEnumerable()
                  group row by row[0] into grouped
                  select grouped;

foreach (var group in groupedRows)
{
    currentPane = new AccordionPane();
    currentPane.HeaderContainer.Controls.Add(group.Key.ToString());

    foreach (var row in group)
    {
        currentPane.ContentContainer.Controls.Add(row[1].ToString());
    }   
}
```

Or if you want to stick with your current non-linq approach:

```
foreach (DataRow dtrow in dtTable.Rows) 
        { 
            bool skip = false;

            foreach (var pane in NavigateAccordion.Panes)
            {
                if (pane.HeaderContainer.Controls[0].Text == dtRow[0].ToString())
                {
                    skip = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!skip)
            {
                string idRow = dtrow[0].ToString(); 
                AccordionPane currentPane = new AccordionPane(); 
                currentPane.ID = "AccordionPane" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString(); 
                currentPane.HeaderContainer.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(dtrow[0].ToString())); 
                foreach(DataRow dtRow2 in dtTable.Rows) 
                { 
                    if(dtRow2[0].ToString() == idRow) 
                    { 
                        currentPane.ContentContainer.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(dtRow2[1].ToString())); 
                    } 
                } 
                NavigateAccordion.Panes.Add(currentPane); 
            }
        }
```

Comment: @mike - just curious? why no linq? you can easily create a similar method without linq but that will include alot of extra work

Comment: i get this error message Error 54 Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'System.Data.DataRowCollection'.  'GroupBy' not found.

Comment: Mainly because i don't know linq well enough to manipulate it to the point i feel comfortable

Comment: @Mike - Updated my answer, both to fix the linq way and to give you an approach without linq (you should call AsEnumerable (not 100% sure about the name) on the datatable

Comment: all I get is AsParalle / AsQueryable

Comment: var groupedRows = from row in dtTable.AsEnumerable()
                  group row by row[0] into grouped
                  select grouped;
maybe?

Comment: +1 just for the quick help and being one of the nicest people on Stackoverflow :)